# Permission denied for all sudo comands

Tags: sudo

I just typed "sudo chmod 770 ." on my /usr/bin directory by mistake

```
[acc]:/usr/bin$ sudo chmod 770 .
```

Now every time i run a sudo command I get a "Permission denied" error

```
[acc]~$ sudo
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

When I open a new terminal, i get: "bash: groups: command not found"

Please help me resolve this... :(

Comment: Update: I tried to restart my machine but it didnt boot. I had to come back in windows.... :'''(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should boot from a LiveCD then do the following:

1. Mount your Ubuntu installation by clicking on the device's icon in the file manager.
2. Open a terminal and `cd` into the `/usr/bin` folder of that installation you mounted from above.
3. Run this command to give all users execute permissions

   ```
   sudo chmod -R a+x .
   ```
4. Run this command to give all users read permissions

   ```
   sudo chmod -R a+r .
   ```
5. Run this command to remove all users (except `root`'s) write permissions

   ```
   sudo chmod -R o-w .
   ```
6. Reboot and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, before I try this. hope you saw the dot at the end of my line " sudo chmod 770 .".And can  I do this using recovery mode?

Comment: @TechyTimo you can try recovery mode, drop to a root shell, run `mount -o remount,rw /` and type those commands (without `sudo` in front). I also added `.` to the end of my commands

Comment: Amazing! You are a genious! It worked and I did not need a LiveCD. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

- boot into recovery mode
- Select root
- Press enter to continue
- Type chmod 755 /usr/bin

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is:

1. Boot into recovery mode with ubuntu. (select advanced options on the grub menu, then Ubuntu with recovery mode)
2. Then, select "Root" in the list of options. That will give you root-permissions in the recovery mode, and you will enter the terminal
3. do: `cd /usr/bin` and then try to do `sudo chmod 777`

(i am not sure if it should be 7777 because that grants access for everyone)

4 . Reboot

Good luck.

Comment: Damn! That didnt work. Getting same error flashing on a black screen when i boot : "could not write pipes , check battery state...

Comment: Okay i suppose you need to boot in a live CD then. Look at the other answer; and follow his steps. Good luck.

Comment: I do not have a cd close here.. can this also work with a usb boot?

Comment: @TechyTimo yes, you just need Ubuntu bootable media. It's generally called a LiveCD